# Функция read() не читает информацию из файлового дескриптора STDIN_FILENO

Tags: linux, c, unix

Вот простенький код для вывода того что ввел пользователь в терминале:

```
#include <help_file.h>

#define MAX_READ 20 

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[MAX_READ];

    if (read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, MAX_READ) == -1) // Считывание из стандартного потока ввода
        errExit("read"); // Если ошибка
    
    printf("The input data was: %s\n", buffer); // Вывод

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Однако после запуска программы терминал ничего не пишет, а просто мигает курсор.
Почему так происходит? Можно ли обойтись без использования стандартных функций stdio (например scanf() )?

Comment: А вы не забыли ввести ровно 20 символов?

Comment: Вводил и 20, и 21, и меньше 20. Теоретически он должен 20 символов, а если они не написаны то он их воспринимает за ' '(пробел), но все равно должен считывать 20 символов. 

Comment: Непонятен вопрос. Что вы написали, то прога и делает. Только ошибка краха проги тут мне нервы трепает, из-за вашего `printf(buffer)`.

Comment: Читает до 20 символов. Если ввели лишние — их выбрасывает. Чо не так? ;)